# Html tags in aspose pdf using xml

Tags: xml, pdf, aspose

I am generating a xml file dynamically and using aspose pdf i am generating a pdf file. Every time i am getting html tags in my pdf file
I am generating like below:

```
stringbuilder strScenarioXML = new stringbuilder(); 
strScenarioXML.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Pdf xmlns=\"Aspose.Pdf\">  <Section PageWidth='612' PageHeight='792' PageMarginTop='5' PageMarginBottom='0.1' PageMarginLeft='30' PageMarginRight='30' IsNewPage='true'>");

   strScenarioXML.Append("<Table MarginTop='5' MarginBottom='5' MarginLeft='15' MarginRight='15' DefaultCellPaddingTop='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingRight='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingLeft='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingBottom='2.0' ColumnWidths='100%'><Border><All LineWidth='1'></All></Border>");
            strScenarioXML.Append("<Row FixedRowHeight='15'><Cell><Border><Bottom LineWidth='1' /></Border><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='true' FontName='Arial' FontSize='10' >Notes Details</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell></Row>");
            strScenarioXML.Append("<Row FixedRowHeight='15'><Cell><Table ColumnWidths='70% 15% 15% 0%' DefaultCellPaddingRight='1.0' DefaultCellPaddingLeft='3.0' DefaultCellPaddingBottom='1.0'>");
            strScenarioXML.Append("<Row FixedRowHeight='15'><Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='true' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8'>Note</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell><Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='true' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8'>Created By</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell><Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='true' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8'>Created Date</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell></Row>");
            for (int i = 0; i < objNote.Count; i++)
            {
                 strScenarioXML.Append("<Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='false' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[" + objNote[i].Comments + "]]>" + " </Segment>  <Segment></Segment></Text></Cell>");
                strScenarioXML.Append("<Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[" + objNote[i].Publisher + "]]>" + "</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell>");
                strScenarioXML.Append("<Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[" + objNote[i].CreatedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm") + "]]>" + "</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell></Row>");

            }
     strScenarioXML.Append("</Table></Cell></Row></Table>");
     strScenarioXML.Append("</Section></Pdf>");

     Aspose.Words.License licWord = new Aspose.Words.License();
                licWord.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic");

                Aspose.Pdf.License lic = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
                lic.SetLicense("Aspose.Custom.lic");

                Aspose.Pdf.Kit.License licKit = new Aspose.Pdf.Kit.License();
                licKit.SetLicense("Aspose.Custom.lic");



                Aspose.Pdf.Pdf scenarioExportPDF = new Aspose.Pdf.Pdf();
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                scenarioExportPDF.PageSetup.Margin.Left = 0;
                scenarioExportPDF.PageSetup.Margin.Right = 0;
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(strScenarioXML);
                scenarioExportPDF.BindXML(xmlDoc, null);
                scenarioExportPDF.Save(msExportScenarioStream);
```

I will get 
 tag in first column objNote[i].Comments, i dont want to show 
 tag in pdf file, for that i am taking it in [![CDATA""]] but still no use.
I dont understand what i am missing..Is aspose doest support it or something else i am missing?? Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code but there were tag errors, e.g.  does not have ending tag. I simplified it and used with the latest release, the final PDF shows the table correctly.

The code

```
string dst = dataDir + "xml.pdf";
StringBuilder strScenarioXML = new StringBuilder();
strScenarioXML.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Pdf xmlns=\"Aspose.Pdf\">  <Section PageWidth='612' PageHeight='792' PageMarginTop='5' PageMarginBottom='0.1' PageMarginLeft='30' PageMarginRight='30' IsNewPage='true'>");

strScenarioXML.Append("<Table MarginTop='5' MarginBottom='5' MarginLeft='15' MarginRight='15' DefaultCellPaddingTop='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingRight='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingLeft='2.0' DefaultCellPaddingBottom='2.0' ColumnWidths='100%'><Border><All LineWidth='1'></All></Border>");
strScenarioXML.Append("<Row FixedRowHeight='15'><Cell><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='true' FontName='Arial' FontSize='10' >Notes Details</Segment></Text></Cell></Row>");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    strScenarioXML.Append("<Row><Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='false' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[comments]]>" + " </Segment>  <Segment></Segment></Text></Cell>");
    strScenarioXML.Append("<Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[publisher]]>" + "</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell>");
    strScenarioXML.Append("<Cell VerticalAlignment='Center'><Text Alignment='Left' IsSpaced='false'><Segment  IsUnicode='true' IsTrueTypeFontBold='false' FontName='Arial' FontSize='8' ><![CDATA[date]]>" + "</Segment><Segment></Segment></Text></Cell></Row>");

}
strScenarioXML.Append("</Table>");
strScenarioXML.Append("</Section></Pdf>");

//Aspose.Words.License licWord = new Aspose.Words.License();
//licWord.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic");

//Aspose.Pdf.License lic = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
//lic.SetLicense("Aspose.Custom.lic");

//Aspose.Pdf.License licKit = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
//licKit.SetLicense("Aspose.Custom.lic");



Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf scenarioExportPDF = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//scenarioExportPDF.PageSetup.Margin.Left = 0;
//scenarioExportPDF.PageSetup.Margin.Right = 0;
xmlDoc.LoadXml(strScenarioXML.ToString());
scenarioExportPDF.BindXML(xmlDoc, null);
scenarioExportPDF.Save(dst);
```

Output is like:

[image: Output pdf]